# How to replace a substring in a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace every `</li>` in a string for an `</li>,` 
I've tried using the `string.replace("</li>", "</li>,");` this works but it only replaces the first occurrence.

I understand I need to use use the `g` flag to match globally but when I put it in the replace method `replace("</li>/g", "</li>");` it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `string.replace(/<\/li>/g, "</li>,");`

Comment: Have you tried searching online?...

Comment: Yes i have. and i came across RegExpre but i cant seem to get it to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
string.replace(/<\/li>/g, "</li>,")
```

You can do this passing a string as well, but [the `flags` field has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and may not work in newer browsers:

```
string.replace("</li>", "</li>,", "g");
```

Comment: `'</li>'.match(/\l/); // ["l"]`, you have forgotten a `/` after the backslash

Comment: @PinnyM The first didnt work for me but the second one worked just fine. Thank you.

Comment: @blackwidow249 indeed the string method has been deprecated.  Modified my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
anotherString = someString.replace(/<\/li>/g, '</li>,');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reGex to replace all the occurrences.

```
var string = string.replace(/<\/li>/g,"<\li>,")
```